# jQuery: Comment list disappears on ajax form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

This may be a bit confusing but I will do my best to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a comment form on each post page, users can submit comments via an ajax form and the submitted comment will be displayed below the form without page reload.

All of this works, until I instruct the comments to show based on their `post_id` and the current post id I'm viewing.

When I do that, each post will start showing its comments only but when I try to submit a comment, the `comment_list.blade.php` loads an empty list of comments instead of adding the new comment to the already existing ones.  I have to refresh the page manually to be able to see the comments.

I have 4 views for the comments:

- leave_a_comment.blade.php (has 2 includes to comment_fields and
  comment_list)
- comment_fields.blade.php (the comment form)
- comment_list.blade.php (the comment list)
- cancel_reply.blade.php (to
  close a reply window)

**EDIT:** I think I found the problem. in `comment.js` the `comment_done_handler()` function is not returning any data.

So if I comment out `$('.comment-list').html(data.comment_list);` the comment list doesn't disappear on new submission. But of course the newly added comment isn't visible until I reload the page.

**EDIT 2:** actually it's `data.comment_list` that is being returned empty in `comment.js` comment_done_handler(data) method.

`comment.js`

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.post-this-comment', function(){
    var form_data = {
        'per_page': $('.comments_per_page').val(),
        'commenter_parent': $('#commenter_parent').val(),
        'commenter_post': $('#commenter_post').val(),
        'commenter_comment': $('#commenter_comment').val(),
        'postid': $('#postid').val(),
    };

    var arr = [
        'commenter_parent',
        'commenter_post',
        'commenter_comment',
        'postid'
    ];

    for (var i in arr, i < arr.length, i++) {
        var elem = arr[i];
        form_data[elem] = $('#' + elem).val();
    }

// console.log(form_data); // something like => Object {per_page: "some_value", commenter_parent: "some_value", commenter_user_id: "some_value", commenter_comment: "some_value"}

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'post_this_comment',
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    request.done(comment_done_handler);
    request.fail(comment_fail_handler);
});

function comment_done_handler(data){
    console.log(data); // data is sent from server
    $('.comment-content').append($('.reply-content .comment-fields'));
    $('.comment-list').html(data.comment_list); // put new list
    $('#captcha-image').attr('src', data.captcha); // put new captchas
    clear_input_fields();
    remove_error_messages(data);
    hide_comment_fields();
}
```

`Comment` Model

```
public static function root_comments($postId) {
    return self::child_comments(0, 'desc')->where('post_id', $postId);
}

public static function child_comments($parent_id, $order='asc'){
    return self::where('parent_id', $parent_id)->orderBy('created_at', $order)->get();
}

public function posts() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

`CommentController`

```
protected function comment_list($per_page, Request $request, Post $post) {
    $postId = $post->id;
    $root_comments = Comment::root_comments($postId);
    $root_with_replies = $this->include_replies_for($root_comments);
    $paginated_comments = $this->paginate($root_with_replies, $per_page, $request);
    return $paginated_comments;
}

public function index(Request $request, Post $post){
    $view_data = self::view_data($request, $post);
    return view('eastgate.comment.leave_a_comment', $view_data);
}

public static function view_data(Request $request, Post $post) {

    $instance = new Self;
    $per_page = session('per_page')?session('per_page'):config('constants.per_page'); // default per page on opening the comment page
    $result['per_page'] = $per_page;
    $result['comments'] = $instance->comment_list($per_page, $request, $post);
    $result['total_comments'] = $instance->total_comments();
    $result['captcha_builder'] = $instance->captcha_builder();
    return $result;
}

public function post_this_comment(Request $request, Post $post) {
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->user_id = Auth::id();;
    $comment->comment = Input::get('commenter_comment');
    $comment->post_id = Input::get('commenter_post');
    $comment->parent_id = Input::get('commenter_parent');
    if($comment->parent_id > 0){
        $my_parent = Comment::find($comment->parent_id);
        $comment->parents = $my_parent->parents.'.'.$comment->parent_id;
    }else{
        $comment->parents = '0';
    }
    $comment->save();
    $per_page = Input::get('per_page');
    $comment_list = view('eastgate.comment.comment_list')
                        ->with('comments', $this->comment_list($per_page, $request, $post))
                        ->with('total_comments', $this->total_comments())
                        ->with('per_page', $per_page)
                        ->render();
    $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'msg' => 'Comment Saved!',
        'comment_list' => $comment_list,
        'captcha'   => $this->captcha_builder()->inline()
    );
    return Response::json($response);
}
```

`comment_fields.blade.php`

```
<div class="comment-fields">
    <div class="row commenter-comment">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <textarea id="commenter_comment" name="commenter_comment" class="form-control comment-field" title="User's comment" placeholder="Comment Text"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row commenter-name-email">
        <input type="hidden" id="commenter_parent" name="commenter_parent" class="commenter-parent" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" id="commenter_post" name="commenter_post" class="commenter-post" value="{{ $post->id }}">
    </div>

    <div class="row commenter-captcha">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success post-this-comment">Comment</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`comment_list.blade.php`

```
<div class="comment-list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12"> 
            <h2>{!! $total_comments !!} comment(s) </h2>

            @foreach($comments as $each_comment)
                <?php 
                    $name_for_display = $each_comment->user->name;
                    $date_for_display = $each_comment->created_at->diffForHumans();
                    $parent_name_for_display = '';
                    if($each_comment->parent_id > 0){
                        $parent_comment = $each_comment->parent();
                        $parent_name_for_display = $parent_comment != null && $parent_comment->name
                                                    ? $parent_comment->name : 'Anonymous';
                        $parent_name_for_display = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt" title="Reply to">&nbsp;</span>'.$parent_name_for_display;
                    }
                    $parents_count = substr_count($each_comment->parents, '.');
                    $offset_length = $parents_count;
                    $comment_length = 12 - $offset_length;
                ?>
                <div class="col-xs-offset-{!! $offset_length !!} col-xs-{!! $comment_length !!}">
                        <input type="hidden" id="postid" name="postid" class="post-id" value="{{ $each_comment->post_id }}">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li class="comment-by">{!! $name_for_display !!}</li>
                        @if($parents_count > 0)
                            <li class="reply-to">{!! $parent_name_for_display !!}</li>
                        @endif
                        <li class="separator"></li>
                        <li class="comment-on">{!! $date_for_display !!}</li>
                    </ul>

                    <p>{!! $each_comment->comment !!}</p>

                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="reply comment{!! $each_comment->id !!}" title="Reply to above comment">Reply</a>

                    <div class="reply-content reply{!! $each_comment->id !!}"></div>

                    <hr>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            {!! $comments->render() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            Show <input type="text" name="comments_per_page" class="comments_per_page" value="{!! $per_page !!}" size="2" title="Number of comments per page"> comments per page
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that if I remove `where('post_id', $postId)` from `Comment` Model, it will start working and reloads the correct `comment_list` with the newly added comment.

I hope that makes sense, and shows the problem I'm facing.

Comment: how about `where('post_id', $postId)->get()`;

Comment: This gives the error `Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), called in Comment.php`

Comment: Can you post the child_comments method as well?

Comment: I've updated the `Comment` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't attempt to execute the code, but this is suspicious:

```
public static function root_comments($postId) {
    return self::child_comments(0, 'desc')->where('post_id', $postId);
}

public static function child_comments($parent_id, $order='asc'){
    return self::where('parent_id', $parent_id)->orderBy('created_at', $order)->get();
}
```

`root_comments`(referenced in the controller's `comment_list` action) is chaining `child_comments`. Except child_comments does not return a query builder object, it returns a collection. You need to remove the `get()` call from child_comments, and instead only use `get()` when you're completely done with building your query.

Also, check out [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) which is a much nicer way of accomplishing what you are trying to do.

**Edit 1 - Example (using scopes):**

> I did not run this code, so there my be syntax errors. This is to better explain the concept.

```
//First, you need to create scopes on the model
public function scopeByParent($query, $parentId, $order = 'asc') {
    return $query->where('parent_id', $parentId)->orderBy('created_at', $order);
}

public function scopeForPost($query, $postId) {
    return $query->where('post_id', $postId);
}

//Then, change your existing methods...
public static function root_comments($postId) {
    return self::byParent(0, 'desc')->forPost($postId)->get();
}

public static function child_comments($parent_id, $order = 'asc') {
    return self::byParent($parent_id, $order)->get();
}
```

Now these are both returning collections as you'd expect. And you can reuse these scopes elsewhere when you need to retrieve the comment records.

**Edit 2:**

The above is part of the problem. The second part of the problem is that you were never retrieving the post that the comment was posted for. I made this change locally and it started to work:

```
public function post_this_comment(Request $request, Post $post) {

    //...
    $per_page = Input::get('per_page');

    //After line 148. The $post that is created by the IoC container is just a reference to the class. You still must load the post from the DB to get the proper data from it.
    $post = $post->find($request->commenter_post);

    $comment_list = view('eastgate.comment.comment_list')
    //...
}
```

Comment: removing `get()` from `child_comments()` will remove the comment_list altogether. My problem is with the where clause in `root_comments()` if I remove it, comment_list will reload with the new comment. You can test the app locally here https://github.com/Halnex/laravel-reddit

Comment: @Halnex - I addressed this. You still need to use `get()`. It is just in the wrong place and it is breaking your `root_comments()` call which is why the data from that call is missing. You are effectively doing this: `self::where('parent_id', $parent_id)->orderBy('created_at', $order)->get()->where('post_id', $postId);` which is not going to give you the results you want.

The `get()` call should be at the end, but it is not.

Comment: I just removed the `get()` from child_comments and added it root_comments, nothing changed, on comment submit the list disappears.

Comment: @Halnex - I apologize for not explaining it clearly. I've added a code example which should help bring clarity to the change I'm suggesting.

Comment: Ok, your code works but it doesn't solve my problem. comment list still disappears when I submit a new comment. If you could just have a look at it on github and maybe make a pull request. I've been at it for a few days now, it's driving me nuts. Btw, it's a reddit clone in Laravel that I will be releasing for free when done. Would love to have you as a contributor.

Comment: @Halnex - I pulled down the code and figured it out. See my second edit. I don't have time to do a proper pull request, but it should get you going. I'll star the project and see if I can contribute from time to time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
public static function root_comments($postId) {
    return self::child_comments(0, 'desc')->where('post_id', $postId)->get();
}
```

-- Before edit ---

Your `comment_done_handler` doesn't fetch the newly created comment list.
You should make another ajax request inside, or maybe as a separate function

```
function comment_done_handler(data){
     var data = $.ajax({
        // ......
       // params sent for this request to comment_list controller method
        data: {
              per_page: 10,
              request: request,
              post: post_id
        },

        type: 'GET',
        url: 'comment_list'
        // ......

    }).done(function() {
       // ....
    }).fail(function(){
      // ....
    });

    console.log(data); // data is retrieved from server
    $('.comment-content').append($('.reply-content .comment-fields'));
    $('.comment-list').html(data.comment_list); // put new list
    $('#captcha-image').attr('src', data.captcha); // put new captchas
    clear_input_fields();
    remove_error_messages(data);
    hide_comment_fields();
}
```

Comment: But it fetches it just fine if I remove the where clause in `root_comments()` are you sure this is the case?

Comment: Check the my edited answer, it seems you forget to add `->get()` method

Comment: Adding `get()` will through an error on page load. I am trying to add the ajax get request inside `comment_done_handler` but it says `request` undefined. so I added my own fields. Now I'm getting `GET /posts/comment_list?commenter_parent=0&commenter_post=1&commenter_comment=test 500 (Internal Server Error)` with `Division By Zero` thrown as well.

Comment: try adding `processData: false`  to ajax request to prevent data being processed and transformed into a query string

Comment: BTW, what does `data.comment_list` in `comment_done_handler` return?

Comment: if I remove the where clause, it returns html markup code with all the comments including the one that was just added. If you'd like you may have a closer look at the app here https://github.com/Halnex/laravel-reddit - just clone it and tinker with it, if u'd like of course.